# Way of hearing myself in my headphones when talking on Skype?

Tags: macos, audio, skype, headphones

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to listen to the input sound on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/58188/is-there-a-way-to-listen-to-the-input-sound-on-mac-os-x)

Is there a way of hearing myself in my headphones when talking on Skype? Essentially intentional feedback.

The reason I am asking, is that my headphones are *really* soundproof, and so I cannot hear how loud I am talking into the microphone. And since I am sitting in an open landscape, my load talking annoys my coworkers...

Using OS X 10.6.8

Comment: fixed. added in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype itself doesn't have any way of doing this.  It can't tell what you want by looking at the headphone jack because that could just be external speakers.

You will need an external tool that routes it that way for you, behind skype's back.

You can try this (i've never used it):

> [LineIn 2.1.0](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11333/linein)  (free)
>   Enables soft audio playthru from input devices.

Comment: Hm... that is the same plugin.  It ends up being a duplicate, I suppose.  Damn.

Comment: Same as what? Where is the duplicate?

Comment: It was posted as a comment to the original question, by @slhck.  I think this one should stay because it specifically addresses skype, and others might not think to look for 'os level' fixes.

Comment: Yup, the question can still be closed though so we have a pointer to the original. /cc @oligofren